# Stopping "not handled in user code" dialog for exception type

Tags: c#, exception, custom-exceptions

Within visual studio I get an dialog saying something like

> "An exception of type XXX occurred in YYY.dll but was not handled in
>   user code"

and pausing my code.  Is there a way in VS2013 of suppressing this just for this one exception type (this is for a custom exception)?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't just handle the exception in your code?

Comment: The alternative is that the default unhandled exception handling takes over and tears down the process. Is that the behaviour you want?

Comment: The exception is handled by a third party library (quick fix) so I don't want to handle the exception.  Just want to stop this from being picked up when debugging in VS.  Is there an option to disable this action?

Comment: @nick updated my answer to answer on that. The message does indicate it wasn't handled though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, handle the exception.

Either:

- fix the issue (like in the case of an `ArgumentNullException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`);
- or if it is something you could expect: use a `try...catch` block (like internet being down causing an exception).

---

If you want to disable messages on *handled* exceptions, you can set when if Visual Studio breaks on a specific exception in the *Debug > Exceptions* dialog. Then uncheck *Thrown* for your specific exception.

Comment: "was not handled **in user code**". Unchecking *Thrown* for this specific exception will not work if "Just My Code" is enabled and "User-handled" is checked for this exception.